# SharePoint search result web part show record with empty field at the end

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results

I am using search result web part and displaying product search results.

`RelatedProductID` is one of the fields on a product item and it is blank in some cases.

Search is working fine but I want to show all products where `RelatedProductID` is not blank on top and then the other products. How can this be done?